# discordjs/nodejs , How can i check if a message only contains custom emotes?

Tags: node.js, regex, discord.js

I'm building my own discordbot in NodeJS by using discordjs.
With the code below you can recognize if the message contains only a emote

```
client.on("message", function(message){
var bool = message.content.match(/^(:[^:\s]+:|<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>|<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>)$/);
```

an emote shows like this when you do an console.log (the emote Kappa as an example) :

> <:Kappa:731053321502326797>

Now it only matches when 1 emote is in the message
But it doesnt match if a message contains 2 emotes with a space between it.

How can i make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
^(:[^:\s]+:|<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>|<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>)+$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Oq0WZp/1).

Explanation:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:\s]+                  any character except: ':', whitespace
                             (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <:                       '<:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:\s]+                  any character except: ':', whitespace
                             (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <a:                      '<a:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:\s]+                  any character except: ':', whitespace
                             (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `g` (global) modifier for the regex. Here are a few input strings to test:

```js
var strings = [
    '<:Kappa:731053321502326797>',
    '<:Kappa:731053321502326797> :smile:',
    'text with :smile:',
    'something else'
];
var re = /(:[^:\s]+:|<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>|<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>)/g;
strings.forEach((str) => {
    var matches = str.match(re);
    console.log(str + '\n==> matches: ' + JSON.stringify(matches));
});
```

Output:

```
<:Kappa:731053321502326797>
==> matches: ["<:Kappa:731053321502326797>"]
<:Kappa:731053321502326797> :smile:
==> matches: ["<:Kappa:731053321502326797>",":smile:"]
text with :smile:
==> matches: [":smile:"]
something else
==> matches: null
```

It is not clear if an input with emoji and other text should fail or not. This version allows combined emoji and other text.